# How to get the replit link for uptime robot?

Tags: python, discord.py, replit, uptime

I have made a super simple discord bot (for study tracking sessions)
and I want it to run 24/7

So from all the google searches,
I found that I could do that with the help of `uptime robot` website and for that purpose I need the **URL/link** of my repl the format should be `http://REPL-NAME--USERNAME.repl.co` (I found somewhere)

But the problem is

> I can't find the link/URL of my repl

[image: My view of the repl window]

any help would be appreciated (plz provide screenshots if possible) !!

i Tried to create my own URL like `http://PythonStudyBotRepl--CodingCircle2.repl.co`

Comment: you eventually need to run a webserver inside your replit

Comment: Yep I just thought that there wasn't a need for running a webserver as it was a simple bot but turns out you need to in order for obtaining a working link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to make the replit host a website. 

You can achieve this by making a `webserver.py` file.**

`webserver.py`

```py
from flask import Flask # Make sure to install the flask package
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/') # The "main" page of the website. The root.
def home():
  return "Webserver OK, Discord Bot OK"

def run():
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target=run) # We use threading so the function doesn't block the discord client from running.
  t.start()

# It's pretty simple, create a simple webserver using Flask so replit gives you a URL to use, when starting the webserver use threading so it doesn't block the rest of the code from running.
```

To call it, 
`main.py` (or whatever the main file is called, `bot.py`, etc.)

```py
from webserver import keep_alive
# [...]
keep_alive()
client.run(TOKEN)
```